# A four-digit number is chosen at random from all four-digit number

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me with this problem? I know four-digit numbers are these from 1000 to 9999. I don't know how to find the probability in that a large range.

> A four-digit number is chosen at random from all four-digit number. Express as a common fraction the probability that the number is divisible by 2, 3,4 and 5.

Comment: There are $9000$ numbers altogether; the probability is just the proportion of those numbers that meet the divisibility test. For example, if the test were divisibility by $250$, the answer would be $36/9000$

Comment: The number of numbers between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive) which are divisible by $k$ (*where $n$ and $k$ are both natural numbers*) is $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor$.  What number, $k$, are you looking for so that it is divisible by all of $2,3,4,5$?  How many numbers between $1$ and $999$ are divisible by $k$?  How many numbers between $1$ and $9999$ are divisible by $k$?  Knowing these, how many then between $1000$ and $9999$ are divisible by $k$?  (Subtraction might be helpful)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: a number is divisible by $2$,$3$,$4$ and $5$ if and only if that number is divisible by $60$. (Why?)

Answer (score 2):

60 is the LCM of 2,3,4,5 .So it would be sufficient to find the multiples of 60 in the range 1000 to 9999.

Comment: That seems like a spoiler - there is a spoiler format that hides the text until the mouse hovers over it that would be applicable here (see advanced help in the editing window)

Comment: @RobertdeGraaf: Why is that? It's an answer to the question -- if the OP only wanted a hint, they could have said so.

Comment: @joriki I read your answer as almost an reply to Fimpllieri above. Re- reading I was incorrect, although my best answer to this question would combine your two answers with your part in spoiler format as described.

Comment: I've just realised that I replied to joriki as if you were mathrox. At this point I realise reading just isn't working for me today and withdraw.